# How to upload a certificate in Unity for an SSL connection

Tags: unity, android, client-server, security, socket

I am developing a videogame in Unity for mobile devices (Android / IOs) that connects to a server through a TCP connection by socket under TLS1.2.
For this reason, my client needs to have the server's certificate (cert.pfx) to establish the connection correctly, and this is where my doubts appear.

How do I load the certificate on the client? I have 2 options in mind but I don't know if any of these are safe and correct:

> A) Include the certificate in the resources directory in the
> compilation of the client application.

> B) Include the certificate in the Streaming Assets directory.

> C) Download the certificate from a URL in the first execution of the
> application and store it locally in the application directory for
> future use.

The truth is that I don't know if any of these options is the right way to go. If anyone has more information about it and can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you would download the certificate at runtime. You would have to download it over an unencrypted connection, so it could potentially be modified (unlikely but not impossible). And it just makes things a lot more complicated for no good reason.

On the other hand, there is no reason why you would not include the certificate with your game installer. A server certificate only needs to include the public key of the server, not the private key (if you give the client the private key of your server, you are doing something very wrong). So the game installer storing an unencrypted server certificate on the users device should not be a problem. The integrity of the certificate is likely already guaranteed by your distribution channel.

Yes, the certificate could get modified by a malware on the device. But when there is a software on the users device which manipulates the game files, then it can screw with the client in any way it wants anyway. So that's a far bigger problem. Also, app packages are better protected from modification than files in the application directory, so having the certificate in the apk/ipa makes it in fact *more* secure from access by 3rd party apps.

So just include the server certificate with the game client.

*How exactly* you bundle the certificate file with your game - referenced Text Asset, Resources folder, asset pack, Addressable or whatever, is a personal preference.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply. It has cleared up quite a few things for me.

As for what it says, if a malware or someone malicious modifies the certificate (generated with the public key) on the client it would not be a problem. The only drawback would be that the communication with the server would stop working, right?

Comment: @AntonioAgustin The reason why someone would do that would be to have the client connect to a different server. That could be a server running a clone of your game. That would usually happen with the consent of your players - some people in your community don't like the way you run your game, so they create their own alternative server for players to play on and instructions how to hack their client to connect to it. Happens in most popular MMOs sooner or later. Another use-case could be a relay to eavesdrop and/or manipulate the data flowing between client and server.

Comment: ohh wow! I had never imagined something like that... I understand perfectly.
Thank you very much for your help.